# Como asignar strings a etiquetas NO input html con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

Me ha surgido una duda de asignar valores dinámicos con javascript sin usar la etiqueta input.

Tengo un

```
<select>
```

que en php almaceno en su "value" un id, que cuando el usuario lo selecciona con el evento "onchange" lanza una query con ese id y recupera unos datos que me gustaría enseñarlos en labels o spans pero sin utilizar la etiqueta "input".

Utilizando los input, con javascript funciona correctamente, pero no me gusta el estilo de los input y me preguntaba si existe otra forma de asignar el valor sin tener que refrescar la página actual.

Un saludo.
Edit: Pongo snippet por comentarios. Lo que intentaba decir, es que cuando ejecutas el javascript con input se le asigna un texto o valores y se muestran en pantalla, mientras que con span, no se muestran en pantalla.

```html
<script>
function showList(){
  var valueOption = document.getElementById("lista").value;
  
  if(valueOption == 1){
    document.getElementById("spanEdited").value = "valor 1";
    document.getElementById("inputEdited").value = "valor 1";
    
  }
  
  if(valueOption == 2){
    document.getElementById("spanEdited").value = "valor 2";
    document.getElementById("inputEdited").value = "valor 2";
  }
}
</script>

<select id="lista" class="form-control" onchange="">
   <option id="null" value="null" onchange="load(this.value);">Selecciona...</option>
   <option id="1" value="1" onchange="load(this.value);">1</option>
   <option id="2" value="2" onchange="load(this.value);">2</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="showList();">Probar</button>
<p>
En span => <span id="spanEdited" value=""></span></br>
En input => <input type="text" id="inputEdited" value="" />
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? ¿Qué dificultades tienes? Sería lo  mismo que con los `input`, pero asignando los datos al otro elemento de tu preferencia. Y, si el motivo es que *no te gusta el estilo de los input*, eso también se puede cambiar vía CSS. En cualquier caso dinos lo que has intentado y por qué elemento te has decidido para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Intente utilizar los "<span id="editSpan" value=""></span> pero al asignar el value en javascript, no se muestra en la página. Sobre el css de los input, digamos que no soy fan de css y estoy utilizando boostrap. Por eso preguntaba si había otra forma. Si solo existe input que lo muestre automáticamente, pues me crearé una clase css para los input específica. Gracias

Comment: No he dicho que con un elemento distinto de `input` no se pueda hacer, puedes hacerlo con `span` o con otro, ahora bien, si ese contenido tiene que ser editable es mucho mejor que lo hagas con `input`. Podemos partir de `span`, entonces pulsa en [edit] y pon el código que estás intentando con `span` y te ayudaremos a resolverlo en base a eso.

Comment: Añadido código de prueba.

Comment: Si lo que necesitas es ofrecer la posibilidad de editar en línea el contenido de diferentes elementos html (p.ej div, span, td, etc.) sin necesidad de incluir inputs y postear su contenido vía ajax (sin forms) es posible hacerlo usando el atributo **contenteditable** de los mismos. Puedes leer al respecto en [W3C-Html spec.contenteditable](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-contenteditable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcto. No te funciona porque el `span` es un elemento distinto del `input`. El `span` es un contenedor, no una caja de texto y por tanto su propiedad `value` no es visible como un `input`.

Eso significa que para mostrar en el `span` el texto tienes que usar un modificador del contenido del mismo. Para este caso es más seguro `textContent`. Podrías usar también `innerHTML` pero este es menos seguro y debes evitarlo cuando el contenido que quieres presentar no va a ser renderizado como HTML.

Veamos un ejemplo con `textContent`.

```js
function showList(){
  var valueOption = document.getElementById("lista").value;
  
  if(valueOption == 1){
    document.getElementById("spanEdited").textContent = "valor 1";
    document.getElementById("inputEdited").value = "valor 1";
    
  }
  
  if(valueOption == 2){
    document.getElementById("spanEdited").textContent = "valor 2";
    document.getElementById("inputEdited").value = "valor 2";
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="lista" class="form-control" onchange="">
   <option id="null" value="null" onchange="load(this.value);">Selecciona...</option>
   <option id="1" value="1">1</option>
   <option id="2" value="2">2</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="showList();">Probar</button>
<p>
En span => <span id="spanEdited"></span><br />
En input => <input type="text" id="inputEdited" value="" />
```

## Recomendaciones

1. No es necesario poner el `onchange` en cada `option`, basta con ponerlo en el `select` y éste se lanzará cada vez que una opción cambie.
2. De todos modos, evita el uso de funciones *in line*. Son consideradas una mala práctica, porque hacen que el código HTML y el código Javascript sean dependientes. Me refiero a invocar las funciones Javascript desde los elementos, como aquí: `onchange="load(this.value);`. Supongamos que usas ese código en miles de archivos o lugares y en un futuro hay necesidad de usar otro valor o dato aparte de `this.value`. Vas a tener que buscar los miles de lugares donde trabjas con ese código para ponerle el nuevo parámetro requerido. Si separas el código, escuchas el `on.change` por el id del elemento en Javascript, podrás modificar el código Javascript sin tener que rebuscar en los HTML. Lo mismo ocurre cuando invocas `showList()` *in line* desde el botón. Es mejor quitar la llamada *in line* y lanzarla escuchando los clicks de ese botón por su id.
3. Decir también que, desde el punto de vista de experiencia de usuario, el código se puede simplificar, operando los cambios en el evento `on.change` del `select`, sin tener que presionar el botón.

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones, las tendré en cuenta. Respecto a la 3. el botón lo puse porque no me funcionaba el onchange en el código de prueba para mostrarlo aquí, en mi local si funciona automáticamente con el código javascript del evento onchange.

Comment: @abeld89 quizá había algo mal y por eso no funcionaba el on change. Es una función inherente a cualquier versión de navegador que tengas por lo que no debería haber problema de compatibilidad. De todos modos, si sigue sin funcionar puedes abrir una nueva pregunta al respecto para revisar a qué se debe que no esté funcionando. Saludos,